# JavaScript slidedown()

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here][1]What do I need to modify in this function 'ShowDiv' to be animated. Example when the cntc div showsup to slide down slowly?

```
function toggle(ele) {
    var cont = document.getElementById('cntc');
    if (cont.style.display == 'block') {
        cont.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Show DIV';
    }
    else {
        cont.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Hide DIV';
    }
}
```

---

More Details:

---

The html file:

```
    <div id = 'Contact'>
    <a href = '#' value = 'Show Div' onclick = "toggle(this);" class = 'btnForm'><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i></a>
    <form id = 'cntc' style = 'display:none' action="https://formspree.io/f/moqpwpwp" method="POST">
        <table class = 'tbl'>
            <tr>
                <td><label text="_replyto">Email</label></td>
                <td><input id = 'frmName' type = 'text'><button name = 'submit' class = 'btnSubmit' type="submit" target = '_blank'>Send</button></td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label text="message">Message</label></td>
                <td><textarea id = 'frmMessageBox'  name = 'message' cols = '40' rows = '3'></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

The js:

```
function toggle(ele) {
var cont = document.getElementById('cntc');
if (cont.style.display == 'block') {
    cont.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Show DIV';
}
else {
    cont.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Hide DIV';
}
```

}

[url=https://ibb.co/99xx4rJ][img]https://i.ibb.co/nsXX1LT/ss.png[/img][/url]

Comment: You want to toggle show/hide between two `divs`?  For example, If `x` is hidden show `y`? Or when `x` is in located at the top of the screen when scrolling show `y`? Or something else? Sorry I think I didn't get the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transition in css. Here's a working solution.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("cntc");
function toggle(el) {
  container.classList.toggle('hide');
  el.innerText = container.classList.contains('hide') ? 'Show DIV' : 'Hide DIV';
}
```

```css
.box {
      width: 450px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #D8E9F8;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .hide {
      height: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id = 'Contact'>    
     <a href = '#' value = 'Show Div' onclick = "toggle(this);" class = 'btnForm'><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i>Show DIV</a>
    <div id="cntc" class="box hide">
        <form id = 'cntc' action="https://formspree.io/f/moqpwpwp" method="POST">
            <table class = 'tbl'>
                <tr>
                    <td><label text="_replyto">Email</label></td>
                    <td><input id = 'frmName' type = 'text'><button name = 'submit' class = 'btnSubmit' type="submit" target = '_blank'>Send</button></td>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label text="message">Message</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id = 'frmMessageBox'  name = 'message' cols = '40' rows = '3'></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. On click, the form is showing up in the first place, but the transition doesn't work.

Comment: @Maryan I updated my answer :). Please take a look at it again. It works with your question now,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Animate Function to scroll to the div smoothly.

```js
function toggle(ele) {
  var cont = document.getElementById('cntc');
  if (cont.style.display == 'block') {
      cont.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Show DIV';
      
  }
  else {
      cont.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Hide DIV';
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#cntc").offset().top},
        'slow');
  }
}
```

```css
#home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}

#cntc {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home"><input id="btnToggle" type="button" onclick="toggle(this)" value="Show DIV"></div>
<div id="cntc" style="display:none;">Hi</div>
```

Comment: No need for a scroll. The form is showing up correctly I just want to show it smoothly.

Comment: Did you mean you need to show like a fade-in effect when the form is displayed?